# How to use 'await/async' in react native?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, async-await, expo-sqlite

I am getting isValidate value from sqlite and routing user to MainTabs or ValidateUser components. But I can not do it because it is not working `async/await` (Or I couldn't.).

`initialRouteName` will be assigned the name of the component to which users will be routed.
Now react native routing to `"ValidateUser"`.

Not: When I try flag async the MainNavigationContainer and I write await directly inside it is throwing error.

Not: I am using `expo-sqlite-orm` for getting data from database

https://github.com/dflourusso/expo-sqlite-orm

```
    //imports truncated...
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator()
    
    //truncated...
    
    const MainNavigationContainer = (props) => {
    
        console.log("MainNavigationContainer props", props)
    
        var initialRouteName = "ValidateUser"
    
        async function validateUserFunc () {
            const validatedUser = await Users.findBy({isAdmin_eq: 1})
            console.log('validatedUser in validateUserFunc: ', validatedUser)
            props.setValidatedUser(validatedUser)
    
            let userIsValidated = validatedUser.isValidated
            let validatedTelNumber = validatedUser.telNo
    
            initialRouteName = userIsValidated === 1 ? "MainTabs" : "ValidateUser"
            console.log('initialRouteName in validateUserFunc: ', initialRouteName)
        }
    
        validateUserFunc()
        console.log('initialRouteName after validateUserFunc: ', initialRouteName)
    
        //truncated...
    
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={screenOptions}
                    initialRouteName={initialRouteName}
                >
                    //truncated Stack.Screen...
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {validateUser, listenMessages, setValidatedUser})(MainNavigationContainer)
```

Users.js entity:

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import { BaseModel, types } from 'expo-sqlite-orm'
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

export default class Users extends BaseModel {
    constructor(obj) {
        super(obj)
    }

    static get database() {
        /*return async () => SQLite.openDatabase({
            name:"ulak.db",
            location:"default"
        })*/

        return async () => SQLite.openDatabase("ulak.db")
        //return async () => SQLite.openDatabase(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/ulak.db`)
    }

    static get tableName() {
        return 'users'
    }

    static get columnMapping() {
        return {
            id: { type: types.INTEGER, primary_key: true }, // For while only supports id as primary key
            userName: { type: types.TEXT, not_null: true },
            userSurname: { type: types.TEXT, not_null: true },
            telNo: { type: types.TEXT, not_null: true },
            deviceId: { type: types.TEXT },
            isValidated: { type: types.INTEGER, default: 0, not_null: true },
            isAdmin: { type: types.INTEGER, not_null: false, default: 0 },//if isAdmin=1 phone owner, it will authentication.
            profilePicture: { type: types.TEXT, default: null },
            registerDate: { type: types.DATETIME, not_null: true, default: () => Date.now() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Users.findBy has to be async.

Comment: @MichaelBahl How to do it? I am using expo-sqlite-orm for getting data from the database. https://github.com/dflourusso/expo-sqlite-orm

Comment: Post the implementation of Users.findBy

Comment: @MichaelBahl I added implementation of Users.findBy

Comment: Cannot find something wrong, can post what error is thrown?

Comment: @MichaelBahl Not throwing any error. Just I cant assign "MainTabs" or "ValidateUser" coming from database data to initialRouteName for routing.

Comment: Wrap the function call ```validateUserFunc()``` with and try catch and print the error.

Comment: @MichaelBahl I tried but did not throw any error.